# how can i solve error when installing expo by using this command (npm install expo-cli --global)

Tags: react-native

[A complete log already exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxVrh.jpg)

i tried reinstall node, clear cache , remove the log file specifies in image but still im getting same error

Comment: Ad  log informations as Text not as link to an image